# C# NHiberate DevExpress.XtraGrid and ServerMode

Tags: c#, nhibernate, pagination, devexpress, xtragrid

Has anyone successfully implemented Server Mode using DevExpress XtraGrid (WinForms) using NHibernate as an ORM? Any examples of how we can use NHibernate To LINQ as a datasource is appreciated, we certainly hope this functionality is available.

Server Mode (XtraGrid)
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8398

Comment: I am surprised no one has any comments. I thought given the popularity of NHibernate and DevExpress components someone would have tackled paging?

Comment: I am currently trying that but it only fetches first 128 rows although sets the correct rows count. When I scroll down in the grid, it doesn't fetch additional rows. I am trying to get their help to resolve the issue. Someone else has reported this before in their feedback forum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with LinqServerModeSource getting the IQueryable from NHibernate Session, but the problem is that you only have a read-only source, The only read enabled data source is XPServerCollectionSource but I think that you have to use the XPO Persistent Framework.